# Why is checkstyle that SonarQube Quality Profile uses different than checkstyle file I provided?

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

While creating SonarQube Quality Profile I provided checkstyle file to it. After Quality Profile wsa created I check which checkstyle (Permalinks) and it is different than one I provided. I am new to this field could you shade some light on it?

Original checkstyle I provided:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="FileContentsHolder"/>
        <module name="CyclomaticComplexity">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="max" value="25"/>
        </module>
        <module name="InterfaceIsType">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="HiddenFieldCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
            <property name="ignoreConstructorParameter" value="true"/>
            <property name="ignoreSetter" value="true"/>
            <property name="ignoreAbstractMethods" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="TypecastParenPadCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="StringLiteralEquality">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="LocalVariableNameCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceBeforeCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RedundantImport">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AnonInnerLength">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="max" value="50"/>
        </module>
        <module name="StaticVariableNameCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParameterName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParenPadCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="FinalClass">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodTypeParameterName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="WhitespaceAfterCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="UpperEll">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="JavadocVariableCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
            <property name="scope" value="public"/>
            <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="TypeNameCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MemberNameCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NeedBracesCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="VisibilityModifier">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="FinalParametersCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
            <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="PackageName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParameterAssignment">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RedundantThrows">
            <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
            <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="IllegalImport">
            <property name="severity" value="error"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="TodoCommentCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="DesignForExtension">
            <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
            <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="JavadocStyleCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="BooleanExpressionComplexityCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="InnerAssignmentCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MagicNumberCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
            <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="JavadocTypeCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="IllegalInstantiation">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="IllegalThrows">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RedundantModifierCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="LeftCurlyCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="TrailingComment">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="LineLength">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="max" value="160"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidStarImport">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="DefaultComesLast">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="OperatorWrapCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EmptyBlock">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodLengthCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EqualsHashCode">
            <property name="severity" value="error"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MissingSwitchDefault">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodParamPadCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="GenericWhitespace">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EmptyStatement">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RightCurlyCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ConstantNameCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ArrayTypeStyle">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="UnusedImports">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="WhitespaceAroundCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ModifierOrder">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="JavadocMethodCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceAfterCheck">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="FallThrough">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
    <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile">
        <property name="severity" value="info"/>
    </module>
    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="severity" value="info"/>
    </module>
    <module name="FileLength">
        <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocPackage">
        <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
        <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="info"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RegexpSinglelineCheck">
        <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
        <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressionFilter">
        <property name="file" value="${samedir}\suppressions.xml"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

checkstyle which SonarQube Quality Profile uses (Permalinks):

```
<!--  Generated by Sonar  -->
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
    <module name="SuppressWarningsFilter"/>
    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="severity" value="info"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocPackage">
        <property name="severity" value="info"/>
    </module>
    <module name="FileLength">
        <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile">
        <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        <property name="lineSeparator" value="system"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="FileContentsHolder"/>
        <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder"/>
        <module name="AnonInnerLength">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="max" value="50"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ArrayTypeStyle">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="AvoidStarImport">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="allowStaticMemberImports" value="false"/>
            <property name="allowClassImports" value="false"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[A-Z]$"/>
        </module>
        <module name="CyclomaticComplexity">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="max" value="25"/>
            <property name="switchBlockAsSingleDecisionPoint" value="false"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_WHILE,LITERAL_DO,LITERAL_FOR,LITERAL_IF,LITERAL_SWITCH,LITERAL_CASE,LITERAL_CATCH,QUESTION,LAND,LOR"/>
        </module>
        <module name="DefaultComesLast">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="DesignForExtension">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EmptyBlock">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
            <property name="option" value="stmt"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_WHILE,LITERAL_TRY,LITERAL_FINALLY,LITERAL_DO,LITERAL_IF,LITERAL_ELSE,LITERAL_FOR,INSTANCE_INIT,STATIC_INIT,LITERAL_SWITCH,LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EmptyStatement">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="EqualsHashCode">
            <property name="severity" value="error"/>
        </module>
        <module name="FallThrough">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="FinalClass">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="GenericWhitespace">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="IllegalImport">
            <property name="severity" value="error"/>
        </module>
        <module name="IllegalInstantiation">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="IllegalThrows">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="ignoreOverriddenMethods" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="InterfaceIsType">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="LineLength">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="max" value="160"/>
        </module>
        <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="allowClassName" value="false"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MethodTypeParameterName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[A-Z]$"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MissingSwitchDefault">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ModifierOrder">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="PackageName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z]+(\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*$"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParameterAssignment">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="ParameterName">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
            <property name="ignoreOverridden" value="false"/>
        </module>
        <module name="RedundantImport">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="StringLiteralEquality">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
        </module>
        <module name="TrailingComment">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
            <property name="format" value="^[\s\}\);]*$"/>
        </module>
        <module name="UnusedImports">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="processJavadoc" value="true"/>
        </module>
        <module name="UpperEll">
            <property name="severity" value="info"/>
        </module>
        <module name="VisibilityModifier">
            <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
            <property name="allowPublicImmutableFields" value="true"/>
            <property name="packageAllowed" value="false"/>
            <property name="publicMemberPattern" value="^serialVersionUID$"/>
            <property name="protectedAllowed" value="false"/>
            <property name="ignoreAnnotationCanonicalNames" value="org.junit.Rule,com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some rules are replaced with java plugin rules, other are mapped/not implemented yet. You should check the map link:

> A majority of the Checkstyle rules have been introduced in the Sonar Java plugin. Copied rules are marked "Deprecated" in the Checkstyle plugin ONLY beacause Sonar plugin have similar rule , but a some summary of [map/replaced rules (a lot of mistakes)](http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/checkstyle.html) is available.

Source https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle